# has anyone considered netty's suceptibility to oCERT-2011-003?

Tags: netty

**Denial of Service through hash table multi-collisions** (http://www.nruns.com/_downloads/advisory28122011.pdf)

I'm hoping someone has a reason why Netty's QueryStringDecoder isn't susceptible to this attack.

From the referenced .pdf

== Java ==
Java offers the HashMap and Hashtable classes, which use the String.hashCode() hash function. It is very similar to DJBX33A (instead of 33, it uses the multiplication constant 31 and instead of the start value 5381 it uses 0). Thus it is also vulnerable to an equivalent substring attack. When hashing a string, Java also caches the hash value in the hash attribute, but only if the result is different from zero.  Thus, the target value zero is particularly interesting for an attacker as it prevents caching and forces re-hashing.

Different web application parse the POST data differently, but the ones tested (Tomcat, Geronima, Jetty, Glassfish) all put the POST form data into either a Hashtable or HashMap object. The maximal POST sizes also differ from server to server, with 2 MB being the most common.

A Tomcat 6.0.32 server parses a 2 MB string of colliding keys in about 44 minutes of i7 CPU time, so an attacker with about 6 kbit/s can keep one i7 core constantly busy. If the attacker has a Gigabit connection, he can keep about 100.000 i7 cores busy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...

Netty is not affected as we limit the header size already. See [1] for more details:

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/141

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Trustin has already considered this.

```
commit 521bf83d0f39896f3c87c54bebd1e8c06e86b60b
Author: Trustin Lee <trustin@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 30 17:58:51 2011 +0900

    Issue #141: hashdos security vulnerability in QueryStringDecoder and possibly other components

    * Limited maximum number of parameters to 1024 by default and made the
    limitation configurable
    * QueryStringDecoder is now able to handle an HTTP POST content

M       codec-http/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/QueryStringDecoder.java
M       codec-http/src/test/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http/QueryStringDecoderTest.java
```

Comment: Yes. Netty 3.3.0 includes this fix.